# how to invoke clangd to format a file

Tags: clang, clang-format

I have a workable version of `clangd` in my bin, but there is no `clang-format`. I want to format a file from command line, how to do this?

In `clangd` [doc](https://clangd.llvm.org/features.html), it says

> clangd embeds clang-format

A standalone `clang-format` can directly format a file from command line. I don't know whether `clangd` can do the same.